# Automate login to google and download a spreadsheet

Tags: c#

My C# application reads and processes Excel file. Recently I moved my spreadsheets to google documents. Now I need to sign in to google and access a particular link(equivalent to export) to get the exported form of the spreadsheet (xls) that my application reads.

I was wondering if there is any way to automate logging to google and getting the xls file to a particular location so that I can avoid the trouble of logging in and downloading the excel file. Any thoughts on this?

(I'm thinking of saving the google credentials and link for the xls file in an xml)

Comment: [This link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) has everything you need for logging in.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this SO question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api)

Comment: Can you consider sharing the file publicly.

Comment: Amazing, that link contains everything needed to access GoogleDocs using a URL and download a spreadsheet for use programatically using  C#, but still down-voted... Interesting.

Comment: I voted it up for you, seems sensible enough to me :S

Answer (score 5):

The [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/overview.html) has [an option to export a spreadsheet](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets) in any supported format.

```
GET /feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=example_spreadsheet_id&fmcmd=4
```

`fmcmd` "4" exports to Microsoft Excel format (xls).

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution to simple download CSV data from Google Spreadsheet. Hope it helps:

https://gist.github.com/dhlavaty/6121814

Notes:

1. Your Google SpreadSheet (Google Drive, Google Docs) document must be set to "**Anyone with the link**" can view it
2. To get URL press SHARE (top right corner) on Google SpreeadSheet and copy "**Link to share**".
3. Now add &output=csv parameter to this link