# what is baseURI field in gData?

Tags: c#, google-docs

I was trying to integrate Google Docs to a Windows app. In the DocReq class there is a property called `baseURI`. I have no clue what it is. Also, let me know if there are any examples for the Google Spreadsheets in C#

Answer (score 0):

The baseURI is simply the base URI for the Document request. This wikipedia article explains a URI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier

Here is another question from Stackoverflow that has some examples about google spread sheets in c#

[Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api)