# Google SpreadSheet API based applications

Tags: c#, excel, google-sheets

I am trying to learn Google Spreadsheet API. Any open source applications that are using this API would be great source to start learning it. I need suggestion on any such applications with code available online.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Spreadsheets Documentation](https://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) pages have info about the general protocol, and Java example code that uses the [Client Library](https://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html).

For a C# example you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api) helpful.