# Getting the Table from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, datatable, google-sheets

We want to gather the info from a google spreadsheet, and are following the [code samples given in the Google Apps Platform help](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list-based_feed).

Using that code, we found the right spreadsheet and the right worksheet (the `Debug` line confirms it to be the right worksheet - there are only two in the whole account).  However, when it comes to fetching the data from the rows, it comes back blank.  So I tried to discover the number of rows, and the count comes back 0, which explains why there was no text forthcoming.

So what am I missing?

```
  Debug.WriteLine("Worksheet Name=" + worksheet.Title.Text);
  // Iterate through each row, printing its cell values.
  foreach (ListEntry row in listFeed.Entries){
      Debug.WriteLine("thisrow=" + row.Title.Text);
  }
  Debug.WriteLine("Number of rows=" + listFeed.Entries.Count);
```

P.S. I've been to [this wonderful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api), but it doesn't mention list-based feeds - only cell-based feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  Solved it:

There was a blank row just below the header row.  Apparently, that breaks the dataset, which explains why I was getting no results.

> The list feed contains all rows after the first row up to the first
>   blank row. The first blank row terminates the data set. If expected
>   data isn't appearing in a feed, check the worksheet manually to see
>   whether there's an unexpected blank row in the middle of the data. In
>   particular, if the second row of the spreadsheet is blank, then the
>   list feed will contain no data.