# How to Access and Insert Data in to Google Spread Sheet using C# and Sheet Api?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can one please help me in **how to access** the Google Spread Sheet Data using there  Google Sheet API using oAuth 2.0 also when the sheet is accessed **how to insert/add** data there online

In .NET C#?
I found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api) but it is using oauth 1 and only accessing the data
Please provide an example or link

Comment: Post your attempt here and we will help you fix it.  Asking for links normally gets your question closed but I have a service account example. http://www.daimto.com/google-sheets-with-c/  If you cant figure out how to change it to Oauth2 edit your question and add your attempt I will help you fix it.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks i have posted the answer as i have found the way. Please look into this one if you can :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660588/error-in-writing-values-for-specific-column-in-google-spread-sheet-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following code that access and write values in columns :

```
string CLIENT_ID = "***";

        string CLIENT_SECRET = "***";

        string SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";

        string REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";


        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

        parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;

        parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;

        parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;

        parameters.Scope = SCOPE;

        string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(authorizationUrl);
        Console.WriteLine("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth "
          + "request token.  Once that is complete, type in your access code to "
          + "continue...");
        parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
        string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine("OAuth Access Token: " + accessToken);

        GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
            new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
        SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
        service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

        SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();

        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

        //foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
        //}

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries[0];
        Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Title.Text);

        // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
        // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
        // app's needs.
        WorksheetFeed wsFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets;
        WorksheetEntry worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)wsFeed.Entries[0];

        // Define the URL to request the list feed of the worksheet.
        AtomLink listFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);

        // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
        ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
        ListFeed listFeed = service.Query(listQuery);


        CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(worksheet.CellFeedLink);
        CellFeed cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);

        CellEntry cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 1, "firstname");
        cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
        cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 2, "lastname");
        cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
        cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 3, "age");

        cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);
        cellEntry = new CellEntry(1, 4, "height");
        cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);

        // Create a local representation of the new row.
        ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
        row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "firstname", Value = "Joe"  });
        row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "lastname", Value = "Smith" });
        row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "age", Value = "26" });
        row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "height", Value = "176" });

        // Send the new row to the API for insertion.
        service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```