# Error in writing values for specific column in google spread sheet in c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have defined a columns in spread sheet manually named as :

- Newly build home?
- Date and Time
- M/F

How to write values for those columns. I have tried

```
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "newlybuildhome?", Value = "Joe"  });
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "m/f", Value = "f" });
  row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "dateandtime", Value = "26" });
  service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```

I get exception that **Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.**

I have tried:

```
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "Newly build home?", Value = "Joe"  });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "M/F", Value = "Smith" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "Date and Time", Value = "26" });
service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```

I get exception with response string :**Attribute name "build" associated with an element type "gsx:Newly" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used other procedure to change the **cell value in a batch.**

The API supports updating an entire column, row, or other set of cells, in a single request. This is offered to improve performance over making large sets of individual requests. This process is called "batching requests"

A number of batch operations can be combined into a single request. The two types of batch operations supported are query and update. insert and delete are not supported because the cells feed cannot be used to insert or delete cells. Remember that the worksheets feed must be used to do that.

query and update can be combined in any size set, and sent to the API in a single request. The API responds with information on the status of each individual operation within the batch. For query requests, the result is the requested cell. For update requests, the result includes the manipulated cell with new values.

```
class BatchCellUpdater
  {
    // The number of rows to fill in the destination workbook
    const int MAX_ROWS = 75;

    // The number of columns to fill in the destination workbook
    const int MAX_COLS = 5;

    /**
     * A basic struct to store cell row/column information and the associated RnCn
     * identifier.
     */
    private class CellAddress
    {
      public uint Row;
      public uint Col;
      public string IdString;

      /**
       * Constructs a CellAddress representing the specified {@code row} and
       * {@code col}. The IdString will be set in 'RnCn' notation.
       */
      public CellAddress(uint row, uint col)
      {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Col = col;
        this.IdString = string.Format("R{0}C{1}", row, col);
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string key;

      // Command line parsing
      if (args.Length != 1)
      {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Syntax: BatchCellUpdater <key>");
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        key = args[0];
      }

      // Prepare Spreadsheet Service
      SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

      // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

      CellQuery cellQuery = new CellQuery(key, "od6", "private", "full");
      CellFeed cellFeed = service.Query(cellQuery);

      // Build list of cell addresses to be filled in
      List<CellAddress> cellAddrs = new List<CellAddress>();
      for (uint row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; ++row)
      {
        for (uint col = 1; col <= MAX_COLS; ++col)
        {
          cellAddrs.Add(new CellAddress(row, col));
        }
      }

      // Prepare the update
      // GetCellEntryMap is what makes the update fast.
      Dictionary<String, CellEntry> cellEntries = GetCellEntryMap(service, cellFeed, cellAddrs);

      CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed(cellQuery.Uri, service);
      foreach (CellAddress cellAddr in cellAddrs)
      {
        CellEntry batchEntry = cellEntries[cellAddr.IdString];
        batchEntry.InputValue = cellAddr.IdString;
        batchEntry.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(cellAddr.IdString, GDataBatchOperationType.update);
        batchRequest.Entries.Add(batchEntry);
      }

      // Submit the update
      CellFeed batchResponse = (CellFeed)service.Batch(batchRequest, new Uri(cellFeed.Batch));

      // Check the results
      bool isSuccess = true;
      foreach (CellEntry entry in batchResponse.Entries)
      {
        string batchId = entry.BatchData.Id;
        if (entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 200)
        {
          isSuccess = false;
          GDataBatchStatus status = entry.BatchData.Status;
          Console.WriteLine("{0} failed ({1})", batchId, status.Reason);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine(isSuccess ? "Batch operations successful." : "Batch operations failed");
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the specified {@link SpreadsheetsService} and uses a batch
     * request to retrieve a {@link CellEntry} for each cell enumerated in {@code
     * cellAddrs}. Each cell entry is placed into a map keyed by its RnCn
     * identifier.
     *
     * @param service the spreadsheet service to use.
     * @param cellFeed the cell feed to use.
     * @param cellAddrs list of cell addresses to be retrieved.
     * @return a dictionary consisting of one {@link CellEntry} for each address in {@code
     *         cellAddrs}
     */
    private static Dictionary<String, CellEntry> GetCellEntryMap(
        SpreadsheetsService service, CellFeed cellFeed, List<CellAddress> cellAddrs)
    {
      CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed(new Uri(cellFeed.Self), service);
      foreach (CellAddress cellId in cellAddrs)
      {
        CellEntry batchEntry = new CellEntry(cellId.Row, cellId.Col, cellId.IdString);
        batchEntry.Id = new AtomId(string.Format("{0}/{1}", cellFeed.Self, cellId.IdString));
        batchEntry.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(cellId.IdString, GDataBatchOperationType.query);
        batchRequest.Entries.Add(batchEntry);
      }

      CellFeed queryBatchResponse = (CellFeed)service.Batch(batchRequest, new Uri(cellFeed.Batch));

      Dictionary<String, CellEntry> cellEntryMap = new Dictionary<String, CellEntry>();
      foreach (CellEntry entry in queryBatchResponse.Entries)
      {
        cellEntryMap.Add(entry.BatchData.Id, entry);
        Console.WriteLine("batch {0} (CellEntry: id={1} editLink={2} inputValue={3})",
            entry.BatchData.Id, entry.Id, entry.EditUri,
            entry.InputValue);
      }

      return cellEntryMap;
    }
  }
```