# How to get data from google spread sheets in c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I want to read the data in google spread using c#.I am able to authenticate google drive but I am unable to read the data in google spread sheet.I have used following code

```
   SpreadsheetsService myService = new SpreadsheetsService("Sample ProjectSheets");
     myService.setUserCredentials(My emailid, My password);
    SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = myService.Query(query);
```

In the above code , I am getting exception at  **myService.Query(query)** as **An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll**  and build the above code by refering following link:[Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api?noredirect=1&lq=1).
I have one more doubt what to mention as ***application name*** in **SpreadsheetsService** object.

Comment: Please show the detail of the exception. Also note that you're referring to an answer from 2009. I would strongly encourage you to use a more recent API, e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet for a .NET quick start

Comment: This is the exception getting for me **An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll**

Comment: In this link https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet . I have doubt in step-3  at this point of code                                        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");                      here What are parameters are passing to **path.combine** method?Is the **.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json** default path or custom path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "default path or custom path". It's just a place to store the credentials for that demo application.

Comment: Okay @JonSkeet . You have said that it is for to store the credentials then where should  i can store in my application.

Comment: Pick a directory... we have no idea what kind of application you're writing, which makes it hard to know where you'd want to store that information. But fundamentally that's not a Google Sheets question...