# Extracting data from Google spreadsheets via API + c#

Tags: c#, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In General I have a problem I can't read the data from the table.
The problem I have is really simple, I'll describe it on the example of the Excel spreadsheet.

Get cell value from table in status, if this cell says "Not sent" or cell is empty in this case, I take from another cell the data in the same row and begin to work with these data.
After successful completion of the task, I set the status "sent" to the cell from which the received data. Here everything is simple, but using the API to do not understand. Already mastered authorization, i.e. using the standard code I can write data to the table, but can not get please, edit code.
Here is the code:

```html
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SheetsQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
            String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may follow this [Google Sheets with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-sheets-with-c/) tutorial. It stated that you will need the NuGet packages from both client libraries. The first one is the current [Google .net client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) which we need to authenticate. The second is the old [Gdata library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.Spreadsheets) which we use to access Google SpreadSheets. You may also refer with this SO post: [Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api)