# How can I automate data entry by column within Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, automation, format, data-entry

I've been researching this a small bit and can't find a concrete solution. Every week I have 2 tabs of reporting data I copy/paste from a .xlsx into a Google Sheet, the columns in the .xlsx do not always match the order as the Google Sheet. Example: Column A, B, and C exist in the .xlsx and Sheet, but one week the order might be C, A, B, another week it could be A, C, B.

Is there a way to import a .xlsx into a Google Sheet where it will automatically append the column data based on a matching header?

Thanks,

I havent tried a whole lot, but have explored external services such as Zapier. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the google sheets API you should be able to figure out how to connect to the API and access the sheets that you have in your google account and manipulate the data in one based on your requirements.

You can find the API Documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

There is also a discussion about manipulating sheets with a lot of useful information here:
[Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api)

Comment: Summarizing the steps and providing sample codes will be more helpful